# SVG <animation> <use> should individually scale and rotate from the centre of there location on the canvas

Tags: animation, svg, symbols

I have been scratching my head and struggling to animate a svg symbol which i would like to rotate and scale from where it is placed on the canvas. Instead of their individual centres, the symbols are all taking the canvas `(0, 0)` as the origin or another location.

[The SVG in action](https://madeinthemoon.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/svgtest.svg)

Basically I would like one instance of `<use>` to rotate back and forth, another `<use>` to scale up and down and a third `<use>` to do both rotate and scale **in it's location**. Eventually I will have around 20 `<use>` with different locations / colours / rotations / scales of the same `<symbol>`.

I definetly don't want to use JavaScript or external resources, just a simple bit of inline? svg code.

And as you can probably see in the code, I am fumbling around, I am still very new to coding.

Unsuccessfully atempts using viewBox, transform, translate probably in the wrong part of the code.

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- Creator: Made in the Moon -->
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs>
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[

    .fily {fill:#FFDA03}
    .filb {fill:#224D8F}
    .filp {fill:#3F2A56}

    .yrot {transform-origin: 15% 11%;}

    .sp {animation-name: sp; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 5s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; transform-origin: center; }
    @keyframes sp {
    0%{transform: scale(0.9);}
    50%{transform: scale(1.3);}
    100%{transform: scale(0.9);}
    }

    .ro {animation-name: ro; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    @keyframes ro {
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg); }
    50%{transform: rotate(90deg); }
    100%{transform: rotate(0deg); }
    }

    .rotateandscale
    {animation-name: rotateandscale; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
    @keyframes rotateandscale {
    0%{transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);}
    50%{transform: rotate(20deg) scale(1.3);}
    100%{transform: rotate(0deg) scale(0.9);}
    }

    ]]></style>
    <symbol id="grow" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M315 155l91 -34c57,20 131,20 188,0l91 34 126 60c3,1 2,0 2,3l-32 131c0,1 0,1 -1,1l-65 -2c-22,118 -13,236 -9,355 -42,48 -78,106 -110,175 -66,3 -126,3 -192,0 -32,-69 -68,-127 -110,-175 4,-119 13,-237 -9,-355l-65 2c-1,0 -1,0 -1,-1l-32 -131c0,-3 -1,-2 2,-3l126 -60z"/>
    </symbol></defs>

    <use id="p-grow" viewBox="0 0 160 160" xlink:href="#grow" class="filp ro" x="65" y="65" height="160" width="160"/>

    <use id="b-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="filb sp" x="-100" y="340" height="80%" width="80%"/>

    <use id="y-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="fily rotateandscale" x="550" y="100" height="50%" width="50%"/>

    </svg>
```

Each instance of `<use>` should individually scale and rotate from the centre of there location on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to transform the shapes around the center, you have to set the value for `transform-origin` to be this center. I hope this is what you are asking.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[

.fily {fill:#FFDA03}
.filb {fill:#224D8F}
.filp {fill:#3F2A56}

/*.yrot {transform-origin: 15% 11%;}*/

use{}

.sp {
transform-origin: 300px 740px;
animation-name: sp; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 5s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; transform-origin: center; }
@keyframes sp {
0%{transform: scale(0.9);}
50%{transform: scale(1.3);}
100%{transform: scale(0.9);}
}

.ro {
  transform-origin: 145px 145px;  
  animation-name: ro; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
@keyframes ro {
0%{transform: rotate(0deg); }
50%{transform: rotate(90deg); }
100%{transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

  .rotateandscale{
  transform-origin: 800px 350px;
animation-name: rotateandscale; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite; }
@keyframes rotateandscale {
0%{transform:scale(0.9) rotate(0deg) }
50%{transform:scale(1.3) rotate(90deg);}
100%{transform: scale(0.9) rotate(0deg);}
}

]]></style>
<symbol id="grow" viewBox="186.8 121 627 760" >
<path id="kk" d="M315 155l91 -34c57,20 131,20 188,0l91 34 126 60c3,1 2,0 2,3l-32 131c0,1 0,1 -1,1l-65 -2c-22,118 -13,236 -9,355 -42,48 -78,106 -110,175 -66,3 -126,3 -192,0 -32,-69 -68,-127 -110,-175 4,-119 13,-237 -9,-355l-65 2c-1,0 -1,0 -1,-1l-32 -131c0,-3 -1,-2 2,-3l126 -60z"/>
</symbol></defs>

<use id="p_grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="filp ro" x="65" y="65" height="160" width="160"/>

<use id="b-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="filb sp" x="-100" y="340" height="80%" width="80%"/>

<use id="y-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="fily rotateandscale" x="550" y="100" height="50%" width="50%"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta this is brilliant! But I am struggling to figure out how you got the origin and viewbox numbers?

Can the `transform-origin` be a percentage so I can easily put the p_grow for instance at `30% 60% ` and the transform-origin as the same `30% 60%`?

Comment: The `transform-origin` is using the coords of the center of the `<use>`. For example in the case of `.ro` x="65" width="160" the x coordinate of the center is 65 + 160/2 = 145. You do the same for the y and you get both center coords for `.ro`. In the case of `.sp` x="-100" and width="80%". Since the svg `viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"` 80% is 1000 * .8 = 800. In this case the x coordinate of the center is -100 + 800/2 = 300

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, thank you so much, really easy to follow whats going on now. Thank you for taking the time to explain this :)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[

.fily{fill:#FFDA03; transform-origin: 800px 350px;}
.filb{fill:#224D8F; transform-origin: 300px 740px;}
.filp{fill:#3F2A56; transform-origin: 145px 145px;}

.sp{animation-name: sp; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 5s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
@keyframes sp {
0%{transform: scale(0.9);}
50%{transform: scale(1.3);}
100%{transform: scale(0.9);}}

.ro{animation-name: ro; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
@keyframes ro{
50%{transform: rotate(90deg);}}

.rotateandscale{animation-name: rotateandscale; animation-timing-function: linear; animation-duration: 10s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
@keyframes rotateandscale{
0%{transform:scale(0.9) rotate(0deg)}
50%{transform:scale(1.3) rotate(90deg);}
100%{transform: scale(0.9) rotate(0deg);}}

]]></style>
<symbol id="grow" viewBox="186.8 121 627 760" >
<path id="kk" d="M315 155l91 -34c57,20 131,20 188,0l91 34 126 60c3,1 2,0 2,3l-32 131c0,1 0,1 -1,1l-65 -2c-22,118 -13,236 -9,355 -42,48 -78,106 -110,175 -66,3 -126,3 -192,0 -32,-69 -68,-127 -110,-175 4,-119 13,-237 -9,-355l-65 2c-1,0 -1,0 -1,-1l-32 -131c0,-3 -1,-2 2,-3l126 -60z"/>
</symbol></defs>

<use id="p_grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="filp ro" x="65" y="65" height="160" width="160"/>

<use id="b-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="filb sp" x="-100" y="340" height="80%" width="80%"/>

<use id="y-grow" xlink:href="#grow" class="fily rotateandscale" x="550" y="100" height="50%" width="50%"/>

</svg>
```